# Load gems inside scripts run from the shell outside our Rails application directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, shell

We have a mail gem installed in our vendor/cache directory inside a Rails application.

The script is called "test" and is not inside the Rails application directory.

```
#! /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby

require 'date'
require 'fileutils'
require 'openssl'
require 'yaml'
require 'mail'
require 'dalli'
```

I get the following error when I execute this script from outside the Rails application.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mail (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

I simply re-installed these gems (mail, dalli) in the standard Ruby path and it worked, but that's not ideal.

What do we need to so that these installed gems are found when we try to run this script outside of a Rails app? In other words, how do we specify the path to these gems?

Comment: do you want to load the rails environment too??

Comment: I really don't need to load the rails environment but if that will fix the issue that I don't mind to add it. How can I load the rails environment through script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that your gem are all declared in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mail'
```

If you don't want them to be loaded by default, and load them only when needed, you can use the `require` statement that you are already using, and in your Gemfile add `:require => false`:

```
gem 'mail', :require => false
```

When you call your script from outside your Rails environment, and want to load the gems, prefix your script by `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec my_script.rb
```

If you need to run your script from another location than your rails's app root, you must run:

```
BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/path/to/your/app/Gemfile bundle exec your_script
```

Keep in mind though that this may cause path issues if your script or your gems are looking for file in the path of your rails app

Comment: My script is not ruby script. Getting this error 'Could not locate Gemfile'  while executing my script from outside rails environment with bundle exec.

Comment: Your script IS a ruby script because it starts with `#! /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby` (even if there is no `.rb` extension). 2 questions: Did you run `bundle install`? Are you in the root of your rails application when starting your script?

Comment: Yes I have already run bundle install and my rails application also working perfectly fine. No , I am not executing my script from the root of my rails application.

Comment: It works perfectly fine If I execute my script from root of my rails appliaction. But I want script should executable from anywhere.

Comment: That a good finding. your gem is in local path of your application, therefore not global, hence your need to run it from your application root directory. I am not sure we can resolve this, but we can try: `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/path/to/your/app/Gemfile bundle exec your_script` (to be executed from the location of your choice)

Comment: Can you please update your answer? so I can accept your answer.